# Slideshow with jQuery shows everything at reload

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm trying to make a simple slideshow to show some information that is contained in a database.

The problem I have is that when the page reloads itself, everything in the slider is shown.
I have no idea how to get around the problem. Here's the jQuery code that I've implemented:

```
$("#filmer > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
    $('#filmer > div:first')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#filmer');
},  5000);
```

Comment: please give the html code too or a reproduce the issue in jsfiddle

Comment: If you call that code from $(document).ready you shouldn't be having such problem.

Comment: I Dosent understand your question sorry to say.

Here is the whole code for the page that the slider shows on:
http://pastebin.com/ksXGz0wB

And the page is:
http://pajhaj-gml.marinex.se/pajhaj/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filmer > div:gt(0)").hide();

  setInterval(function() {
    $('#filmer > div:first')
     .fadeOut(0)
     .next()
     .fadeIn(1000)
     .end()
     .appendTo('#filmer');
    },  5000);
});
```